# Find the owner of an existing project number

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, service-accounts, google-developers-console

A long time ago a former colleague created a project in the Google Cloud Platform to access Google Analytics from a third party BI tool. I want to make adjustments to this project but currently no one knows who this person was or what E-Mail / user account he or she used.

Is it possible to retrieve the user from a Google Cloud project number or a Google service account (.....@developer.gserviceaccount.com) or is there any other way I may have missed to find out who that user was?

Thank you.

Comment: am i understanding correctly that you do have the project number of `12345-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`?

Comment: Do you have the service account JSON key file or just the service account email address? Do you have the credentials to access Google Analytics? Edit your question with details.

Comment: Users do not own service accounts. Therefore, there is no relationship between a user who created a service account and the service account itself except for an audit record for the action.

Comment: @Totem Yes, I have the project number and service account in this format.

Comment: You can search the project via the project number in the main project list.
If the user you're looking for hasn't taken any extra steps and was the one that created the project you should see the user as one of the owners of the project.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to find the project number that was used to create the service account.  Even if you could there would be no way of finding out which user account it is that owns it.

You will need to crate a new project with a new service account.

Comment: Hello Linda, the service account 12345-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com belongs to Google Cloud project with number = 12345. When you open https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=12345, it will open the GCP project and you will see the projectId. That said, I agree : if you have no permissions, there is no way to see who is in IAM